# [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client (and also related to promise problem )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
//get the trending rates
exports.getTrendingRates = async (req, res) => {
  let comArr = [];
  await quoteModel.find({}).then((result) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      comArr.push({
        PL: result[i].PL,
        PD: result[i].PD,
        CS: result[i].CS,
        CT: result[i].CT,
      });
    }
    let finalRes = comArr.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
      let isElemExist = acc.findIndex(function (item) {
        return (
          item.PL === curr.PL &&
          item.PD === curr.PD &&
          item.CS === curr.CS &&
          item.CT === curr.CT
        );
      });
      if (isElemExist === -1) {
        let obj = {};
        obj.PL = curr.PL;
        obj.PD = curr.PD;
        obj.CS = curr.CS;
        obj.CT = curr.CT;
        obj.count = 1;
        acc.push(obj);
      } else {
        acc[isElemExist].count += 1;
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);

    //getting the most search most quotes
    let sortedData = finalRes.sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count);
    let returnObj = {
      id: req.params.id,
      sortedData,
    };

    //filter function to searched user most search quotes in rates collections

    sortedData.forEach(async (value) => {
      const filter = {
        $and: [
          { PL: { $regex: value.PL, $options: "i" } },
          { PD: { $regex: value.PD, $options: "i" } },
          { CS: { $regex: value.CS, $options: "i" } },
          { CT: { $eq: value.CT } },
        ],
      };

      await ratesModel
        .find(filter)
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(result);
          return res.status(200).send({ result });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });
  });
};
```

**I don't know why i am getting this error, even i am not using more than one response. please guys check this code and help me out. I have checked everywhere but got false expectations. oftentimes got this error generally happened by using more than one response. **

Comment: This code is impossible to follow in the question itself because it has improper indentation.  The only way I could understand it was to copy it all into a code formatter and then reformat it properly so I could read it.  Please post readable, properly indented code in your questions.  That will also make it much more likely that you get people helping you.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this error is attempting to send more than one response to the same incoming request.  And, you are doing exactly that.

This code:

```
     await ratesModel.find(filter).then(result => {
          console.log(result)
          return res.status(200).send({result})
     })
```

Is inside a `sortedData.forEach()` loop so as long as the array has more than one item in it, you will be calling `res.status(200).send({result})` more than once which will generate the error.

I don't know what result you want to send in this particular code, but the usual solution is to accumulate the result in your loop and then send the one final accumulated result after the loop.

FYI, your pattern of `await xxxx.find().then().catch()` is making your code a whole lot harder to read, write and debug.  Either use `await` or `.then()`, consistently not both in the same statement or function.  They are a coding style that solve the same basic problem so you should decided which coding style you're going to use within a function and be consistent.

Comment: thanks buddy! i'll prefer await approach @jfriend00